# Postgres calling function throwing error when executed through ssis execute sql task

Tags: ssis-2012, postgresql-9.6, stored-functions, set-returning-functions

I am trying to call this function through execute sql task. But getting this error

```
select spf (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query " select spf (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" failed with the following error: "ERROR [42883] ERROR: function spf(unknown, unknown, unknown, bigint, bigint, bigint, unknown) does not exist;
>   Error while executing the query". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

direct call from postgresql pgadmin is working, which  means it's able to insert the values using the below command.

```
select spf ('POSTG-I0001','2019-02-16 00:00:34','2019-02-16 00:00:00',3,3,3,'Success')
```

adding schema name already tried.

```
create or replace function spf (varchar(100),varchar(50),varchar(50),integer,int,int,varchar(50))
RETURNS Table (
splog_interfaceid varchar(100),
splog_starttime varchar(50),
splog_endtime varchar(50),
splog_deliveredrowcount integer,
splog_processedrowcount int,
splog_sourcerowcount int,
splog_jobstatus varchar(50)
) As $$ 

Begin 

insert into public.splog (interfaceid,starttime,endtime,deliveredrowcount,processedrowcount,sourcerowcount,jobstatus) values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7);
Return Query Select * from splog;

END; $$
```

Comment: Did you map 7 variables to your SQL task?

Comment: Yes mapping and everything is in place. Also if i am running a simple select now() query its working perfectly fine. only the parameters causing concern

Comment: A function that returns a table should be used like a table: `select * from spf(...)`

Comment: @AyushSingh are you using OLEDB connection or ADO or ODBC?

Comment: using ado.net connection